# THEE.JSONLoader Object as public variable

Tags: json, function, variables, three.js

I was wondering if its possible to add an object that is loaded via THREE.JSONLoader as public variable?  Ideally, I'd like all my loaded textures, material creation, and geometry to be public variables at the top of my script for easy manipulation (I have strong 3D background but new to js and webGL).  I'm finding that my public vars that are declared something - are no longer public once they're added as a parameter to a function - in this case the JSONLoader. However, just naming a var, without declaring its value "runs" but I get weird THREE.min.js error I can't comprehend.  I've included my code below - know it has other issues - please feel free to let me know how bad it is - it helps me learn :)

```
//webGL

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

camera.position.set(0, 16, 25);
camera.rotation.x += -0.32;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 1000, 256); // parameters: near, far, resolution
cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter; // mipmap filter
scene.add(cubeCamera);

///LOADERS
var loadTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var loaderJs = new THREE.JSONLoader();


///TEXTURES
var skyTexture = loadTexture.load("textures/background.jpg");
var seatTexture = loadTexture.load("textures/abc_Diffuse.jpg");

///MATERIALS
var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map: skyTexture
});
var frameMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    //envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,
    color: 0xffffff
});
var seatMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: seatTexture
});


///GEOMETRY and MESHES 
var frameGeo;

var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 30, 30);
var skySphere = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMaterial);
scene.add(skySphere);

loaderJs.load("models/stoolFrame.js", function (){
    frameGeo = new THREE.Mesh(frameGeo, frameMaterial);
    frameGeo.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameGeo);
});

loaderJs.load("models/stoolSeat.js", function (seatGeo){
    seatGeo = new THREE.Mesh(seatGeo, seatMaterial);
    seatGeo.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(seatGeo);
});


var barStool = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(barStool);

    var render = function () {

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        barStool.rotation.y += 0.01;

        frameGeo.visible = false;
        cubeCamera.position.copy(frameGeo.position);
        cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
        frameGeo.visible = true;


        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };



render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading your stoolFrame, you forgot to add the parameters for the callback function, check the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader) example. The callback function takes a geometry and a material. When loading the stoolSeat you forgot the material aswell (provided you have a material for the stool)

```
var frameGeometry;
var frameMaterial;
var frameMesh;
loaderJs.load("models/stoolFrame.js", function (geometry, material){
    frameGeometry = geometry;
    frameMaterial = material
    frameMesh = new THREE.Mesh(frameGeometry, frameMaterial);
    frameMesh.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameMesh);
});
```

Above is an example on how to make the geometry, material and mesh into global variables. However you probably dont need to save the geometry and material as global vars (you can access them from the mesh anyway: `frameMesh.material; frameMesh.geometry`).

If the parameter names are the same as a global variable name, javascript will use the parameter variable instead of the global one when trying to access it.

Comment: Big help thankyou!  the frameMaterial = material was a big key to the puzzle I was missing.

Comment: @ab3d_work if the answer solved the problem you were having, then please mark it as the correct one by clicking the check to the left of my answer :).

Comment: I just did a little earlier :)  so that material = frameMaterial works great.  Now I'm trying to create a chrome material (using cubeCamera) on geometry that being uploaded via JSONLoader.  I'm finding that the geometry declared in a global var doesn't seem to be as friendly as a global material in a JSONLoader.  It needs to be global so I can call the update on cubeCamera for rendering.  If you could lend any insight, it would again be a huge help for his!.

Comment: @ab3d_work I dont understand why geometry should need to be treated any differently than material in this case. Maybe if you link a jsFiddle / Codepen with the problem it would make it clearer..?

Comment: I agree.  However when I take the same approach the frame geometry doesn't load. I've tried setting var frameGeo = new THREE.Mesh(); at a public var without any success.  He's a link to the fiddle

Comment: @ab3d_work Doesnt look like you doing what i suggested in my answer. To have a global mesh variable, you have to declare it outside the JSONLoader callback function, and then assign it inside the callback function. see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhbcw29y/).

Comment: you're right! I wan't using it correctly but now I see what you mean. I appreciate the comments in the code and time you put into this - its been a huge help with my learning.  I was hoping that by setting the mesh as a global variable it would be visible to my cubeCamera settings(like the sphere). However i get a "Cannot set property 'visible' of undefined" (in chrome) with this method.  I need to look further into this but if you have any suggestions they'd be much appreciated :)